# Plottable.js Custom Formatters

Tags: javascript, plottable

Does anyone know how to achieve custom formatting when using [Plottable.js](http://plottablejs.org/). You used to be able to pass in a function to the `Custom()` method to format your numbers, like so:

```
let customFormatter = new Plottable.Formatter.Custom(someCustomFunction);
let yAxis = new Plottable.Axes.Numeric(this.yScale, 'left').formatter(new Plottable.Formatter.Custom(customFormatter))
```

Any idea how to do this in the latest release?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!